# submit Callable to ExecutorService when condition is met

Tags: java

I have a class that extends Callable, which does a pretty heavy job. I wish to execute this Callable object once a special criteria is met. Currently my solution looks like this:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
while (is.available() <= 100) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PooledTCPConnector.class.getCanonicalName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    }
}

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable        task = new BackgroundWorker(is, Encoding);

Future<Object>  TaskResult = executor.submit(task);
HTTPResponse HttpResponse = (HTTPResponse) TaskResult.get();
```

I don't like that Thread.Sleep in the while loop, and would really like to get rid of it. Is there any way to schedule the task within the executor without a fixed delay, until a criteria is met?

IMPORTANT: External Frameworks/jars sadly can not be used, because our developers have no file system access to the target system thus unable to deploy dependency jars. Only Java 1.6 solutions are acceptable beside this requirement, also because the limitation of target system.

Comment: So you want to build something like async io? Why not use nio or some framework that supports its usage?

Comment: Nop. I want to execute the Callable object when the is.available returns more than 100. Nothing more nothing less. As you can see Currently I wait until it is the case, which is not really elegant. Wait & Notify could be used but then again that's another Thread which, for this job is an overkill.
About the frameworks you have a point I'm updating the question.